# How to include flash within the html on hover

Tags: html, flash

I was wondering if I could include some flash animation within the html on hover,

thanks

Comment: Basically I needed to make the earth spin on http://www.aroundtheworldin80dishes.net only when the mouse is hovering over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an [external interface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) doing what you want and then call it on hover from your javascript.

> The ExternalInterface class is the
>   External API, an application
>   programming interface that enables
>   straightforward communication between
>   ActionScript and the Flash Player
>   container– for example, an HTML page
>   with JavaScript. Adobe recommends
>   using ExternalInterface for all
>   JavaScript-ActionScript communication.